# How to detect/define string style using kotlin?

Tags: android, file, intellij-idea, kotlin, styles

I want to know how to detect if the string from a textView is writen in bold or not.

For example:

> textView.text = "I love **Stackoverflow**" // that what you should see in TextView

It must return a string contain only the BOLD TEXT:

```
if ( textView.text.style is BOLD) then //that's just an Algorithm to explain
myString = "Stackoverflow"
```

Comment: A `String` does not have style. A `String` is just a sequence of characters, nothing more. A `TextView` might be set up to show the entire text in bold, and a `SpannedString` could have a bold portion (using a `StyleSpan`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect BOLD text in file using kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037382/how-to-detect-bold-text-in-file-using-kotlin)

Comment: @WIKOSO please do not ask the same question multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Try to use spans.

```
        val tv = TextView(this)
        tv.text = Html.fromHtml("I love <b>Stack</b><i>Overflow</i><b>!!!</b>", Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE)
        val spannedString = tv.text as SpannedString
        val allSpans = spannedString.getSpans(0, tv.text.length, Any::class.java)

        //You can check spans; Please check that your span is StyleSpan
        ((allSpans as Array<Object>)[0] as StyleSpan).style == Typeface.BOLD //<b>Stack</b>
        ((allSpans as Array<Object>)[1] as StyleSpan).style == Typeface.ITALIC //<i>Overflow</i>
        ((allSpans as Array<Object>)[2] as StyleSpan).style == Typeface.BOLD //<b>!!!</b>

        //or get start and end
        spannedString.getSpanStart(((allSpans as Array<Object>)[0] as StyleSpan)) //start index of "Stack"
        spannedString.getSpanEnd(((allSpans as Array<Object>)[0] as StyleSpan)) //end index of "Stack"
```

And finally, you can get substring between start and end

**Update**

```
                val spannedString = Html.fromHtml("" +
                "<b>1. Quels sont les facteurs de risque de la maladie athéromateuse ?</b><br>" + //BOLD 0
                "<b>a. Tabac</b><br>" + //BOLD 1
                "<b>b. hypertension artérielle</b><br>" + //BOLD 2
                "c. alcool<br>" +
                "d. Hypertriglycéridémie<br>" +
                "e. diabète<br>" +
                "<br>" +
                "<b>2. Parmi les facteurs de risque cardio-vasculaire, on ne retrouve pas :</b><br>" + //BOLD 3
                "a. Hypercholestérolémie<br>" +
                "b. <b>Insuffisance rénale</b><br>" + //BOLD 4
                "c. Tabagisme actif<br>" +
                "d. Sédentarité<br>" +
                "e. Sexe masculin<br>" +
                "3. Le tableau de dissection aiguë de l&#39;aorte ne comporte pas de :<br>" +
                "a. Hémopéricarde<br>" +
                "b. insuffisance mitrale aiguë<br>" +
                "c. Hémothorax<br>" +
                "d. Accident vasculaire cérébral<br>" +
                "e. Paraplégie", Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE)


        // Find All bold substrings
        val allBoldSpans = spannedString.getSpans(0, spannedString.length, Any::class.java).filter {
//This is BOLD span?
            it is StyleSpan && it.style == Typeface.BOLD
        }

        val ONLY_BOLD_SUBSTRINGS = allBoldSpans.map {
//Extract BOLD text into output collection
            spannedString.substring(spannedString.getSpanStart(it), spannedString.getSpanEnd(it))
        }

it will return array with

    0 = "1. Quels sont les facteurs de risque de la maladie athéromateuse ?"
    1 = "a. Tabac"
    2 = "b. hypertension artérielle"
    3 = "2. Parmi les facteurs de risque cardio-vasculaire, on ne retrouve pas :"
    4 = "Insuffisance rénale"
```

Comment: check this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F2RgPRw0w6FC6PscDPpkem0S12OTYJlj/view) to understand i want to detect the bold text in this doc i know how to extract etc but i don't now how to detect the bold text

Comment: maybe I got you wrong, and can you explain your problem? "i don't now how to detect the bold text". I answered how to find occurrences of bold substrings (see update for full example). Your spans is NOT StyleSpan? Or you have an any issues?

Comment: i'm creating an multi-choices app, so in the document i sent to you..there is the question + the choices (including the correct answers which they are written in bold) i know how to get all the text but my problem is how to separate the correct answers(written in bold ) from the other choices...so please if you have any idea help me!

Comment: I trying to help you. Without the code it is not very easy. I trying to understand, what format of the text you have.

My example is wrong? What wrong in this example? What happens when you substitute your data into the code from the example? The result is incorrect (not all bold strings was extracted or any issues)?

As I understand, you already has a textview with spanned text, right? If the text has spans as my example all shoud work fine.

Comment: Otherwise if your text is not "spanned string" we need to find any bold markers. Or maybe you used "split" function (this function will remove spans and you cant to convert string to spanned). Or you have "custom" format from docx library...

If we understand what source data and what markers in them we can find solutions faster.